# Word for bringing supply chain into a business

Tags: vocabulary

For example, a company that makes telephones might develop expertise in chip making thereby avoiding reliance on a 3rd party supplier.

What is the word or term for this business practise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a business world, that process is called [vertical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_integration) which means:

> an arrangement in which the supply chain of a company is owned by that company. Usually each member of the supply chain produces a different product or (market-specific) service, and the products combine to satisfy a common need.

[Wikipedia]

The term [backward integration](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/backwardintegration.asp) is used when you *purchase* a supplier that produces a part or component of your product. It means:

> a form of vertical integration that involves the purchase of
>   suppliers. Companies will pursue backward integration when it will
>   result in improved efficiency and cost savings.

[Investopedia]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to ***'In-House Production:***

> - In-house refers to conducting an activity or operation within a company, instead of relying on outsourcing. A firm uses its own employees and time to keep a division or business activity, such as financing or brokering, in-house.

The process is called ***[internalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internalization_theory):***

> - Internalization theory focuses on imperfections in intermediate product markets.
>     and occurs only when firms perceive the benefits to exceed the costs.

(www.investopedia.com)